# What is the most universal way to run a command in root on startup?

Tags: linux, command, startup

I have a program that needs to have a command running on startup (the command needs to run as root). I know there are many ways, but what is the most universal way across Linux distributions.
The command stays running until shutdown, by the way, as a service/daemon/etc.
Thanks

Comment: What does "in root" mean? Do you mean the command needs to be run by the `root` user, or that the command needs to be run on the `/` directory or both? And when you say "universal", are you only referring to Linux systems or other *nix as well?

Comment: root user, just linux

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details about the program. What is it supposed to do? What does it need to access? Does it just do a few things and terminate? Or does it need to stay running as a daemon/service?

Comment: A systemd unit.

Comment: Since it will depend on the init system and that there is just no init system *universally* installed, then you won't find any *"universal way"* to achieve your goal. If your need concerns your system only, please tell what your init system is. If you need to deploy your solution to other a priori unknown systems then you'll need to test.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

"Universal" way where a program doesn't requires another program to execute itself.

Create a script and place it over to `/etc/init.d`. When the system will boot up, inside that `init.d` directly whatever you'd have will be executed.

Or if you don't want to directly just place a program or a program that contains several other dependencies, you can create a symbolic link instead.

For example

```bash
echo "echo 'Hello world!'" | tee -a /opt/myscript

# Now create a soft symbolic link
ln -s /opt/myscript /etc/init.d
```

Make sure use these commands as root user (sudo, doas) and also make sure the script or program you linking or placing in `/etc/init.d` have "execute" permission.

Comment: `/etc/init.d` has been deprecated in most modern distros and nothing placed in it will start automatically on boot. Even for the remaning SysVinit distros this is **not** enough. You have to add the script to the appropriate run levels (3 or 5).

Comment: The current way to do this is using systemd. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd

Answer (score 0):

Use systemd, it's standard for most linux distros